# In Powershell how can I convert a string with a trailing 'sign' to a number?

Tags: powershell, globalization, type-conversion

I need to convert strings with optional trailing signs into actual numbers using Powershell.

Possible strings are:

- 1000-
- 323+
- 456

I'm trying to use System.Int.TryParse with a NumberStyles of AllowTrailingSign, but I can't work out how to make System.Globalization.NumberStyles available to Powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: as per Halr9000's suggestion

```
$foo = "300-";
$bar = 0;
$numberStyles = [System.Globalization.NumberStyles];
$cultureInfo = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo];

[int]::TryParse($foo, $numberStyles::AllowTrailingSign, $cultureInfo::CurrentCulture, [ref]$bar);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowTrailingSign
```

I should also point out, that when I'm dealing with enums in general, sometimes I can get by typing a string. E.g. in this case, just put

```
"AllowTrailingSign"
```

Final note, when quizzing an Enum for all possible values, use the line:

```
[System.Globalization.NumberStyles] | gm -static
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way to get the enum values:

```
$type = [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]
[enum]::GetValues($type)
```

Comment: Seems to me you mean: $type = [System.Globalization.NumberStyles];[enum]::GetValues($type);

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the signs could be - or +, String.Replace could help.

If you mean that 323- should return -323, checking for the sign and multiplying it by -1 would help.